# JavaFX 2 printing job

Tags: java, printing, javafx-2

I have a **javafx** application and now I want to print out a receipt but **javafx 2** doesn't support printing. So, what all options I have thought of :

- creating a PDF using core java + pdfbox and printing it
- create an html page but how to print it?
- *awt* printing?

Any other options i have ? Am i thinking the right way?

Please do elaborate and the api required for its development.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Move to JavaFX8 and try this: http://java.dzone.com/articles/introduction-example-javafx-8

Comment: I have made the complete application using java fx 2. Using fx 8 might create problems ? Actually I tried switching to fx8 but there were problems like black flickering screen.

Comment: i have used javafx api to print a node for a reciept 80x80 mm receipt but now i need to print multiple receipt without showing it on screen how i will acheive it